# Passing user input to ProcessStartInfo.Arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got what I think is a simple question.

I'm attempting to create a basic web form which has a user input textbox, a button to run a process and a label or textbox to display the result of the process.

The trick is, I would like the user input to be used as the value for the "StartInfo.Arguments" property in my code.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MyApp
{
public partial class InputTest : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process MyProcess = null;
        string MyProcessOutput = null;
        string MyProcessInput = null;

        try
        {
            MyProcess = new Process();


            MyProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            MyProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

            MyProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\sysWOW64\myapp.exe"; // Command to run
            MyProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = ...  //Where I would like to put user input
            MyProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            MyProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            MyProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            MyProcess.Start();


            MyProcessOutput = MyProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MyProcessOutput = "An error occurred:\r\n" + ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (MyProcess != null)
                MyProcess.Dispose();
        }

        MyProcessOutput = MyProcessOutput.Replace("\r\n", "<br />\r\n");

        myresultsLabel.Text = MyProcessOutput;
    }
}
```

}

The key here is this line:

```
  MyProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = ...  //Where I would like to put user input
```

Any ideas for a textbox, userinput or other way to get the data from the user into that particular property?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: why not put a `asp:TextBox` on the page, give it a name (say `txtArguments`) and then just use `MyProcess.StartInfo.Arguments =txtArguments.Text` to get the text there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `TextBox` in the page, give it a name like `argumentsTextBox`, and code it like:

```
MyProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = argumentsTextBox.Text;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm my friend. Thanks a bunch, I couldn't tell you how long I was scouring the earth for this one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by user input but I'll try to answer from my `C#` experience - user input that is received at runtime:
In my app, I create a process which executes a file. I handle the process's IO, and when input is required, the executing module uses a handler for that.
It's `WPF`, so the executing module knows only an interface which is implemented by my application. When user input is required, a popup will show.